# Not able to GET parameters functioning in include_once

Tags: php

when i call include once without any GET parameters it works but with setting GET parameters on    trackinglogs.php nothing happens please suggest me what do to..

my php code is: firstfile.php

```
include_once('trackinglogs.php?todo=setcookie');
?>
```

my second file is trackinglogs.php

```
<?php
    $action=$_GET['todo'];
    switch($action)
{
    case "setcookie":
    echo "hi";die();
    break;

    default:
    echo "error"; die();
    break;
}

?>
```

thanks for you precious time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot pass parameters when including like that, `include` does not make an HTTP request.

The most minimal solution, *although I do not recommend it*, is to simply set the parameters yourself so that `trackinglogs.php` finds them:

```
$_GET['todo'] = 'setcookie';
include_once('trackinglogs.php');
```

A much better solution would be to put the code that tracks logs inside a function, and call that providing this operating parameters at the same time. So you 'd have something like:

```
<?php    
function track($action) {
    switch($action) {    
        case "setcookie":    
        echo "hi";die();    
        break;    

        default:    
        echo "error"; die();    
        break;    
}
```

And you would do:

```
include_once('trackinglogs.php');
track('setcookie');
```

Comment: is there any function in php where i could make get request along with includes