# include_once not working when parameters are added

Tags: php

Why `include_once();` does not work when url parameters are added?

For example,

this works:

```
<?php include_once("test.php"); ?>
```

and this does not:

```
<?php include_once("test.php?param=name"); ?>
```

Is there any way how to achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: [Try here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937261/not-able-to-get-parameters-functioning-in-include-once)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including a php script is more or less like including the code at the place where you put the `include` statement. No http request is made so no `$_REQUEST` / `$_POST` / `$_GET` variables are set.

Instead, you can use variables from your main script directly in the included script.